# Conjugated diene t-buOK reaction

Tags: elimination

Why does the t-buOK abstract the following hydrogen. Doesn't it promote the Hoffman product so it should take the hydrogen from a secondary carbon instead of a tertiary one? Thank you[image]

Comment: Because the resulting anion makes the ring aromatic.